# How does Cakephp multidimensional array from MySQL left joins?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

For has many or has many through relations,

How does Cakephp return multi-dimensional arrays?

For example something like below:

```
array(
0 => array("CatOne" => array("One" => "Two"), "CatOneOne" => "Oneone"),
1 => array("CatTwo" => "Two"),
2 => array("CatThree" => "Three")
)
```

Please bear in mind I'm creating a custom framework of mine and not using Cakephp!

I could have a look in Cakephp core but wanted to check with others before

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your question i would like to see output array of has many relations like

```
//Sample results from a $this->User->find() call.

Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                    [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => More on Gwoo
                    [body] => But what of the ‘Nut?
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
                )
        )
)
```

you can also refer Very useful Document provide by [CakePHP.org](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

And it also define detail work of relation with model.

Let me know if i could help you more.

Comment: I'm not using Cakephp I just want to build a new framework with one of the functions outputting like Cakephp does as per above

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper doesn't stop you looking at the documentation that shows [exactly what you ask](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany).